# Textarea event handling with Python3

Tags: python, cgi

I wonder if someone can help me. I'm trying to do something like the following to get input events from a HTML text box and send them to a python function.

```
textarea = cgi.FieldStorage()
chars =  textarea.getvalue('1')

def MyPythonFunction(): 
        'Do something with chars'

print(<textarea oninput=MyPythonFunction() </textarea>)
```

I've tried all kinds of things but can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, the **oninput** keyword of the **textarea** HTML tag expects JavaScript code and would interpret **mypythonfunction** to be a JavaScript function. You need to output an HTML **form** that contains a **SUBMIT** tag such that when the form is submitted it invokes your server-side script: the form might look like:

```
<form name="f" action="my_script.py" method="post">
    <textarea name="chars"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Your server side script, **my_script.py**, which must be executable, might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
chars = form.getvalue('chars')
```

If you really wanted to process input a character at a time, then you would remove the **SUBMIT** HTML tag, put back the **oninput** keyword. But then you would have to specify a JavaScript function that would get invoked whenever the contents of the textarea changed. This function would have to use a technique called AJAX to invoke your server-side Python script passing the contents of the **TEXTAREA** as an argument. This is a rather advanced topic, but you can investigate this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice I took it and have found a way to do it. However, it uses php on the server side. In order to grab the variable it uses $q = $_REQUEST["q"]; and then at the end uses:  echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint; So my question now is what would be the Python equivalents of these: Thanks again.

Comment: No worries i've figured it out now